Run ARIMA without xreg when they're completely rank deficient?
Q: In the context of forecasting many series with exogenous regressors in the R tidyverts/fable framework, is there a way to tell fable::ARIMA(y~x1+x2+...) to fail over to running its routine for ARIMA(y) for each series where all combos of exogenous regressors x are rank deficient (e.g., because x1, x2, ... are all just zeroes) instead of returning a null model?
Below I set up a minimal working example. As I expected, when a particular exogenous regressor is just a column of zeros, fable::ARIMA() just drops it, estimating a model with the remaining exogenous regressors. But, surprisingly to me, when all exogenous regressors are zero and ARIMA() drops them all, it produces a NULL model. Ideally, I'd just be able to tell ARIMA() that I want to run it's routine for ARIMA(y) in these cases.
Q: But if that's not an option, what can I do? Do I attempt some sort of try-catch? Is there a tidy way of doing this?
This is related to my question Specify exogenous regressors conditionally for each series in ARIMA?. There I ask about the general case of specifying different regressors for different series which might arise, e.g., from best subset regressions over many series. Specifying no regressors when they're all zero and the full set when they're not might be a way of handling this. But here, I'm really looking for straightforward tidy approaches which are intended to work for this special case.
set.seed(123)

# create data
tibble(idx=1:12,group='aa',y=rnorm(12)) -> aa
tibble(idx=7:12,group='bb',y=rnorm(6)) -> bb
tibble(idx=1:6,group='cc',y=rnorm(6)) -> cc
tibble(idx=1:12,
       x1=c(0,0,1,rep(0,9)),
       x2=c(rep(0,9),1,0,0)) -> xreg
bind_rows(aa,bb,cc) %>% 
  inner_join(xreg,by='idx') %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=idx,key=group) -> dat
dat %>% print(n=Inf)
# # A tsibble: 24 x 5 [1]
# # Key:       group [3]
# idx group       y    x1    x2
# <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 aa     1.15       0     0
# 2     2 aa    -0.231      0     0
# 3     3 aa    -0.365      1     0
# 4     4 aa     0.158      0     0
# 5     5 aa     0.766      0     0
# 6     6 aa     0.426      0     0
# 7     7 aa     0.927      0     0
# 8     8 aa     0.0461     0     0
# 9     9 aa    -0.504      0     0
# 10    10 aa    -0.300      0     1
# 11    11 aa     0.823      0     0
# 12    12 aa    -0.849      0     0
# 13     7 bb    -0.954      0     0
# 14     8 bb     0.313      0     0
# 15     9 bb     0.612      0     0
# 16    10 bb    -1.69       0     1
# 17    11 bb     0.785      0     0
# 18    12 bb     0.0119     0     0
# 19     1 cc    -0.181      0     0
# 20     2 cc     1.11       0     0
# 21     3 cc     1.48       1     0
# 22     4 cc    -1.15       0     0
# 23     5 cc     1.01       0     0
# 24     6 cc    -0.632      0     0

# Everything as I'd expect. No problem here. 
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y)) -> fit.y
fit.y
# # A mable: 3 x 2
# # Key:     group [3]
# group          arima
# <chr>        <model>
#   1 aa    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>
#   2 bb    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>
#   3 cc    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>

# Still, everything as I'd expect. Just a warning message which follows. 
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1+x2)) -> fit.yx1x2
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y,xreg=dat%>%select(x1,x2))) -> fit.yx1x2
# Warning messages:
# 1: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x1` 
# 2: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x2` 

# For group bb, x1 dropped and x2 retained, as I'd expect
# For group cc, x2 dropped and x1 retained, as I'd expect
fit.yx1x2 %>% pull(arima) %>% map(c('fit', 'par'))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       1.56      0.777     2.01   0.0679
# 2 x2      -0.446     0.777    -0.574  0.577 
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x2        1.79     0.875      2.04  0.0873
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       -1.07     0.625     -1.71   0.139

# Now there's an error. I was surprised by this. 
# Sure, for group bb, x1 is just a column of zeros. 
# But if it's removed shouldn't the model estimated by the same as the one as
# if I had specified `ARIMA(y)`, as above, as if `x1` had never been mentioned?
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1)) -> fit.yx1
# Warning messages:
# 1: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x1` 
# 2: 1 error encountered for arima
# [1] subscript out of bounds

# A NULL model is estimated for group bb, rather than `<ARIMA(0,0,0)>` as above
# when I had specified `ARIMA(y)` without `x1`
fit.yx1 %>% pull(arima) %>% map(c('fit', 'par'))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1        1.56     0.787      1.98  0.0712
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       -1.07     0.625     -1.71   0.139

# the following is to create a tibble with one row for each group
# and a tibble for each group, to be used in `. %>% model(arima=ARIMA(<my formula>))`
# though I don't know how to continue this approach and, basically, say
# -ARIMA(y~x1+x2) for group aa,
# -ARIMA(y~x2) for group bb,
# -ARIMA(y~x1) for group cc
# in a tidy way.
# But, also, I don't think this is even the right approach. 
# `fable::ARIMA()` was intended to be used once, for the entire dataset, with
# all series. It wasn't intended to be called once for each series, here, that
# being 3 times, once for each of series groups aa, bb, cc
dat %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  group_by(group) %>% summarise(across(x1:x2, \(.x) any(.x!=0))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=x1:x2, names_to='x', values_to='keep') %>%
  inner_join(
    dat %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols=x1:x2, names_to='x', values_to='value'),
    by=join_by(group, x)
  ) %>%
  filter(keep) %>% select(-keep) %>% 
  nest(data=-group) %>%
  mutate(data=map(data, \(.dat) pivot_wider(.dat, names_from=x, values_from=value) %>% 
                    as_tsibble(index=idx))) -> dat.series

dat.series
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
# group data             
# <chr> <list>           
#   1 aa    <tbl_ts [12 × 4]>
#   2 bb    <tbl_ts [6 × 3]> 
#   3 cc    <tbl_ts [6 × 3]> 

dat.series$data
# [[1]]
# # A tsibble: 12 x 4 [1]
# idx       y    x1    x2
# <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 -0.560      0     0
# 2     2 -0.230      0     0
# 3     3  1.56       1     0
# 4     4  0.0705     0     0
# 5     5  0.129      0     0
# 6     6  1.72       0     0
# 7     7  0.461      0     0
# 8     8 -1.27       0     0
# 9     9 -0.687      0     0
# 10    10 -0.446      0     1
# 11    11  1.22       0     0
# 12    12  0.360      0     0
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1]
# idx      y    x2
# <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     7  0.401     0
# 2     8  0.111     0
# 3     9 -0.556     0
# 4    10  1.79      1
# 5    11  0.498     0
# 6    12 -1.97      0
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1]
# idx      y    x1
# <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  0.701     0
# 2     2 -0.473     0
# 3     3 -1.07      1
# 4     4 -0.218     0
# 5     5 -1.03      0
# 6     6 -0.729     0


Looks like a bug. I've reported it at https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/404

A package author pointed out in comments that model(ARIMA(.)) returning a <NULL Model> for group bb is a bug.
In my original post, my hack solution was some logic which constructed different training data sets depending on the values of exogenous regressors over each group, e.g., which created a different data set for group bb. But I think what I've done below is a better hack solution.
The bug kindly returns a <NULL Model>, for which one can easily check with fabletools::null_model(). I just estimate a safety model and use that as my final model in these <NULL Model> cases. Of course, this treats all cases, not just the rank deficient exogenous regressor case, which induce model(ARIMA(.)) to return a <NULL model> with the same safety model. But I'm actually ok with that.
Note: I'll mark this as the accepted answer if some time has passed without any better answers.
# Package author pointed out in comments that `model(ARIMA(.))` returning a null 
# model for group `bb` is a bug. 
# In my original post, my hack solution was some logic which constructed 
# different training data sets depending on the values of exogenous regressors 
# over each group, e.g., which created a different data set for group `bb`.
# But I think what I've done below is a better hack solution. 
dat %>% 
  model(
    arima=ARIMA(y~x1),
    safety=ARIMA(y)
    ) %>%
  suppressWarnings() %>%
  mutate(
    final=if_else(is_null_model(arima), safety, arima)
      ) -> 
  fit.yx1

# Everything appears as I expected
print(fit.yx1)
# # A mable: 3 x 4
# # Key:     group [3]
# group                       arima         safety                       final
# <chr>                     <model>        <model>                     <model>
#   1 aa    <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,0) errors> <ARIMA(0,0,0)> <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,0) errors>
#   2 bb                   <NULL model> <ARIMA(0,0,0)>              <ARIMA(0,0,0)>
#   3 cc    <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,0) errors> <ARIMA(0,0,0)> <LM w/ ARIMA(0,0,0) errors>

# Everything appears as I expected
fit.yx1 %>% pull(final) %>% map(c('fit', 'par'))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#   1 x1        1.56     0.787      1.98  0.0712
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 0 × 5
# # ℹ 5 variables: term <chr>, estimate <dbl>, std.error <lgl>, statistic <dbl>, p.value <dbl>
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 x1       -1.07     0.625     -1.71   0.139

